# Is there a way to run a python script by clicking on an icon on e.g. the desktop?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, desktop-application

I have a GUI python script that runs perfectly well when I run it in the terminal, however I would like to remove the need to use terminal and just be able to click on an icon (like an application) to have the script run and open the GUI. Is there any way to do this? (detail appreciated) Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: Are you using Windows? Depending on the OS you use, there might be different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its pretty doable.
you can use [NSIS](https://pypi.org/project/pynsist/) to make an executable for windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found Pyinstaller to be the easiest to use. From terminal just do 'pip install pyinstaller'. Then once it's downloaded cd to the directory that contains the file. From there just run 'pyinstaller file-name' and it will create it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do that:

-Save as filename.pyw

-use pyinstaller to build a filename.exe file with the --noconsole option

[Pyinstaller Usage](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)